# How can I auto-end the media process on Android?

Tags: task-management, auto-start, media-scanner

Media is consistently topping the list for battery usage at 80%+. I can go and force stop it, but it restarts by itself, when I use things such as camera or download things etc.

Task manager does allow you to auto end applications, but as media is not an application it is not on the list. Is there and app or any other way to auto-kill media on a NON rooted phone?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it would be far more useful to find out why the media scanner is using so much of your phone's battery.

I had a similar situation once, and it turned out to be caused by some filesystem corruption on the SD card. I took out the SD card and used `fsck` on my PC to check the filesystem for errors, and repair it. I then put the SD card back in my phone: media scanner ran once and finished normally. It no longer ran all the time, running down my battery.

You might like to try something similar before you attempt something that might stop apps on your phone (such as Gallery) working properly.

Answer (score 1):

The "media process" gets triggered by different applications. Some of them you already encountered: Camera and Download. Basically apps which add new media (or manipulate existing ones). They are signaling the media scanner that there are changes to process (so the media database gets updated). As the media scanner is, simply spoken, just a "system process", you don't see a related app.

Auto-Killing would not be very helpful in this case (for the described reasons, media scanner must do its job or e.g. the gallery wouldn't find your fresh shot pics). It rather might be that some app requests its services much to frequently (that was the issue in another case I encountered recently, but I don't remember the app causing it). So you would need to find the culprit causing that (not killing the obedient servant): Go through all the apps you've installed and check which one might deal with media (if the problem just started recently, it's even easier as you can concentrate on those recently installed/updated). See if you can temporarily disable/remove them, and if the problem is gone with that. If so, re-enable them slowly one-by-one until the problem re-appears – which is when you just re-enabled the culprit which thus is identified. That's the app you either need to find a replacement for, or have the dev fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Done a factory reset, used super backup and transferred some files to PC before the wipe. My battery life is back to normal now... 18 hours.